# TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined in React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux, react-redux

I currently have jsx in my React component that will return certain features based on if there is a certain value in an object. For example in my React component:

```
if(customer.product.id === "543"){
    return (
      <div className="text-align-left">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-12 font-weight-bold">
            <p>Some text here</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="text-align-left">
        <div className="row">
          <p>Different text here</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

'customer' is coming from my Redux state and dispatching appropriately, and is as follows:

```
{
  "product": {
    "id": "543",
  },
  "info": [
    {
      "name": {
        "title": "Mr",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
      },
      "dob": "1956-06-06",
      "phone": [
        {
          "number": "5555555555",
          "ext": "234",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I know it is dispatching correctly because if I try to access customer.info[0].name.last_name in the jsx, it returns the correct value.

Yet, when I try to get the value for customer.product.id I am met with the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

From reading other questions here, it seems the issue may be that the object I'm getting from the Redux state is asynchronous, but if it is able to go in and access customer.info[0].name.last_name, why can't it do the same with customer.product.id? I tried using a try catch block, but that didn't work out either (also, having an if else statement in a try catch isn't exactly dry code). Much of the other questions I found on here with this issue when using React were dealing with a component with a local state an.

I apologize if this question is a duplicate of another question, but I can't seem to find a question that fits this situation. Thank you!

Comment: Can you check if you `console.log(customer)` just before your if statement, you get the same output as above?

Comment: Sure, console.log(customer) returns { info: [ { name: [Object] } ] }, I don't know why it is only showing the property that has an array as it's value.

Comment: its not returning the product though. So, can you post the code when you are getting the data from the store? I am assuming there is some problem where you assigned the customer variable.

Comment: Please add the code to your fetch and how you transform the response into a "customer".